# Unsupported dimention error with imshow function

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I tried to show an image in matlab. The dimentions of the image was <15360x15360x3 uint8> so when I showed this in matlab I had lots of trouble with CPU usage and RAM. I couldn't zoom, pan and do other tasks.
so I resized my image with paint
no the trouble is after resizing dimentions of the image get <7680x7680x4 uint8> and when I use 'imshow' I encounter the error
**??? Error using ==> imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData at 114
Unsupported dimension**
That is because of 4
Does anyone has an idea what I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the **fifth** time you've posted a question about the Image Processing toolbox tonight. I strongly suggest you begin *reading the documentation for the functions you are using!*

In this case, `doc imread` will get you the following snippet:

> imread
>
> Read image from graphics file  Syntax
>
> ```
> A = imread(filename, fmt)
> [X, map] = imread(...)
> [...] = imread(filename)
> [...] = imread(URL,...)
> [...] = imread(...,Param1,Val1,Param2,Val2...)
> ```
>
> Description
>
> `A = imread(filename, fmt)` reads a grayscale or color image from the
>   file specified by the string filename. If the file is not in the
>   current folder, or in a folder on the MATLAB path, specify the full
>   pathname.
>
> The text string fmt specifies the format of the file by its standard
>   file extension. For example, specify 'gif' for Graphics Interchange
>   Format files. To see a list of supported formats, with their file
>   extensions, use the imformats function. If imread cannot find a file
>   named filename, it looks for a file named filename.fmt.
>
> The return value A is an array containing the image data. If the file
>   contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the file contains
>   a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array. For **TIFF files**
>   containing color images that use the **CMYK color space**, A is an
>   **M-by-N-by-4 array**. See TIFF in the Format-Specific Information section for more information.

Microsoft Paint is changing the format of your TIFF file when you save it. This is the same problem you were having in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889709/save-a-tiff-image-without-changing-its-bit-depth-and-compression-type/9889819#9889819). The solution is to use a different image editing program, like [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: thanks. I had read documentation about imread but the main problem was **imshow** function does not show M-by-N-by-4 arrays.As you suggested I started to use GIMP and now I think the problem is fixed

Comment: The actual problem is that the MxNx4 array had the image in the CMYK colour space, where `imshow` expects RGB. The fact that the matrix dimensions didn't agree with `imshow()` is incidental to the fact `imshow` has no idea how to deal with CMYK. You can convert between colour spaces, but it's nasty.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the size of the image in Matlab:

first, filter the image (optionally):

```
sigma = 1;
flt = fspecial('gaussian', (2 * sigma + 1) * [1, 1], sigma);
img_filt = imfilter(img, flt, 'symmetric');
```

then re-sample the image every freq pixels:

```
freq = 2;
sub_img = img_filt (1 : freq : end, 1 : freq : end, :);
```

I don't think, the paint does something smarter when resizes images.

Comment: Not quite what the OP asked (she already asked how to resize an image in a different question.) As a sidenote, the `imresize()` function will perform smoothing and downsampling in one step - try `imresize(img,scaling_factor,'bicubic')`.

Comment: good to know about imresize(), but it must be new (not in R2010b).

Comment: regarding relevance of my solution, I suggested to solve the original problem (too large image for imshow) rather than resulting paint format problem.

Comment: `imresize()` is most certainly in R2010b (I have R2010a and it's there.) It is, however, in the image processing toolbox.